# Expansion Of A algebric term

Tags: propositional-calculus

While doing a coding for software I fell upon in the need to expand the following expression

$(A \land B) \land (C \land (D \lor (E \land f)) \land (g \lor h \lor i))$

I tried it and result I got is following

$$((A \land B \land C \land D )\lor( A \land B \land c \land (e \land f)) ) \land (g ) \lor ((A \land B \land C \land D )\lor( A \land B \land c \land e \land f) ) \land (h) \lor ((A \land B \land C \land D )\lor( A \land B \land c \land e \land f) ) \land (i)$$

Please veify if my answer is correct or help me to find the correct answer

Update: I went through the expression again and i found the earlier expansion was incorrect and below given should be correct please verify

((A and B and C and D )and (g) or ((A and B and C and D )and (h) or ((A and B and C and D )and (i) or ( A and B and c and (e and f)) )and  (g) or ( A and B and c and (e and f)) )and  (h) or ( A and B and c and (e and f)) )and  (i)

I am sorry I cound not format the question correctly I am new to the website

Comment: You can verify equality by software: simply evaluate both for all possible A, B, C, D... There are only $2^9 = 512$ cases, so an easy job for a computer. There are also symbolic manipulation packages for binary expressions, but you don't seem to need those here.

Comment: Which software are you talking about Is the software free Please give a pointer.

Comment: You can easily write one in any programming language: 9 nested for loops, etc.